# populating a new instance of a class within a subscribe function

Tags: javascript, angular, class, subscribe

This code works as is, except it briefly flashes the wrong data due to the fact that I instatiate a blank token before populating it right away in the subscribe function. Is there a way I can move my instantiation into the subscribe function, or to feed the class all the necessary parameters to construct it instead?

```
{
  this.tokens.push(new Token(this.i));
  this.tokenService.generate().subscribe((data: Token) => this.tokens[this.i] = {
    // user_id: this.tokens[this.i].user_id,
    copied: false, id: this.i++,
    access_token: data.access_token,
    expiration: data.expiration
  });
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but couldn't you just "not do that"?  Just remove your first line of code:   this.tokens.push(new Token(this.i));

Answer (score 0):

```
this.tokenService.generate(this.i).subscribe((data: Token) => {
    this.tokens.push(data);
});

// tokenService 
public generate(i: number): Observable <Token> {
    const token = new Token(i);
    return this.httpClient.post<Token>().pipe(map(res => {
        token.access_token = res.access_token
        ...
        return token;
})
// look at constructor of Token, it's better to put some logic there
// the code is not working, just an example
```